# ubuntu upgrade to 16.04, windows 8 does not boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have searched and read most of the threads about this problem. But my problem is different.

Most people get the grub but it does not show windows boot option.

However, in my case, the grub looks exactly the same as before, it shows both ubuntu and windows boot options.
Before I upgrade the ubuntu, I can choose any of them to boot and without the problem. Now, I can still boot Ubuntu but if I choose to boot Windows, the screen becomes purple and nothing happens. Whatever key I press makes no sense. Only the ctrl+alt+delete works and it results in the grub bootloader again. So booting Ubuntu is the only choice.

Does anyone know how to boot Windows?
Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Is this a UEFI machine with Windows installed in UEFI mode?  Did you try the EFI menu (some function key at power-on) to boot Windows directly, skipping grub?

Comment: I have no problem to boot Windows if I put the Windows bootloader above Ubuntu bootloader. In this way, I cannot have any choice but only boot to Windows. What I want is that even if the Ubuntu is placed above Windows and the gurub2(for ubuntu) is shown and I can choose to boot any of the system. This is true before I upgrade the Ubuntu.  The problem that I could not boot Windows comes after I upgrade. I think you might not really understand my problem.@ubfan1